# Mongos fails to reconnect to DB replica after network interruptions

Tags: linux, mongodb, sockets

We're using mongos 3.2.6 and recently discovered that when network connectivity to the DB nodes fails and is restored after a few minutes our mongos processes will not reestablish the connections to our DB nodes.

Our log looks like this:

--Network issue started--

`2017-06-15T08:43:10.723Z I NETWORK  [replSetDistLockPinger] All nodes for set config_server are down. This has happened for 2 checks in a row. Polling will stop after 28 more failed checks`

`2017-06-15T08:43:10.723Z W SHARDING [replSetDistLockPinger] pinging failed for distributed lock pinger :: caused by :: FailedToSatisfyReadPreference: could not find host matching read preference { mode: "primary" } for set config_server`

`2017-06-15T08:43:10.723Z I SHARDING [Balancer] couldn't create config.actionlog collection: :: caused by :: FailedToSatisfyReadPreference: could not find host matching read preference { mode: "primary" } for set config_server`

-- time passes with similar socket and connectivity exceptions --

`2017-06-12T08:57:45.806Z I NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitorWatcher] SocketException: remote: (NONE):0 error: 9001 socket exception [RECV_TIMEOUT] server [<IP>:<PORT>]`

-- similar messages like this appear--

--Network issue is resolved and these log entries continue to appear but mongos is still not operational--

`2017-06-15T10:13:37.024Z I ACCESS   [conn2704] SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed for admin on admin from client 127.0.0.1 ; ReplicaSetNotFound: None of the hosts for replica set config_server could be contacted.`

Mongos service is restarted and it works as normal.

Why doesn't mongos check for connectivity to the DBs after the pooling stops?
How can I make it connect when network is restored?

Comment: the connection retry was made from 127.0.0.1 ? ("...on admin from client 127.0.0.1")

Comment: Yes, thats what it says in the log.

Comment: So you did: mongo localhost -u admin -p myAdminPass --authenticationDatabase admin --authenticationMechanism SCRAM-SHA-1

Comment: and if you do this from remote (not localhost), it will cause the same error ?

Comment: The command is actually "mongos localhost...". The software running on the node is attempting to connect to the local mongos instance to then work with mongodb instance on another host. Monogos however is not able to establish that connection or is not functional at all. In fact, I'm not able to connect to the mongos on the node at all with "mongos localhost..".

Comment: what steps you have done for troubleshooting ?

Comment: So far I have managed to reproduce the issue on a test environment where I do "ifdown eht0", a few minutes later I do "ifup eth0" and observe the above error messages in the log. I attempted to do "flushRouterConfig" in mongos but I'm not able to connect to the local monogs instance. I also restarted the mongos service and this fixes the problem but manual intervention is not the way to solve this.

Comment: But you see with "sudo lsof -Pn|grep LIST" that the port is open ? and if yes, you use telnet to connect to the localhost:port and you get a connection ? did you tried what is written here ? --> https://help.compose.com/v2.0/docs/mongodb-debugging-connections

Comment: The port is open. Telnet, nc and http access to the mongos is successful. However, mongo connections to the mongos from other hosts and from the host to itself fail. My mongo connection string is correct because after restart of mongos service this same connection string is able to connect.

Comment: then sounds like a bug. try to ask for similar issues in a mongo-specific board ?

Comment: Yeah it sounds like it. I've already posted to their google group mongodb-user. Is there a better mongo-specific board you know of?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148029/discussion-between-lkj-and-vladimir).